# MPMusicPlayerControllers nowPlayingItem not changing song

Tags: ios, media-queries, mpmediaitem, mpmediaplayercontroller

`MPMusicPlayerControllers` `nowPlayingItem` no longer seems to be able to change a song. I picked up an old app of mine and was surprised to find this bug. The code use to work 1-2 years ago, but seems to be broken on iOS 16 and 17. The fact that you can only test this on a physical device makes it even harder to debug since I no longer have any iOS 15 devices. I've tried a bunch of different variations to get this to work but nothing does. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller) seems to indicate I’m doing things correctly.

In the code sample below, a song should start playing and then after 3 seconds it should change to a different song. Instead only the first song plays. I am getting the following errors in the console when the second one is suppose to start.

```
Attempted to register account monitor for types client is not authorized to access: {(
    "com.apple.account.iTunesStore"
)}

Failed to set now playing item error=<MPMusicPlayerControllerErrorDomain.5 "Unable to play item <MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x9e9f0ef70> 206357861099970620" {}>
```

The songs are on a local playlist which is downloaded to the phone used for testing. I am an Apple Music subscriber if that makes any difference. Neither of these things have change in the last few years since this code was working though.

```swift
import MediaPlayer

class Test {
    let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer
    
    init() {
        let myPlaylistsQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
        let playlists = myPlaylistsQuery.collections!.filter { $0.items.count > 2}
        let playlist = playlists[0]
        let songOne = playlists[0].items[0]
        let songTwo = playlists[0].items[1]
        
        player.setQueue(with: playlist)
        play(songOne)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.play(songTwo)
        }
    }
    
    
    private func play(_ song: MPMediaItem) {
        player.stop()
        player.nowPlayingItem = song
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    }
}
```